# Why is the OnReceive function not working on my Xamarin Android Widget?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm making a widget for android, and I have a button on a simple form. For some reason, the button keeps working and then not working; even when I made no modifications to the code or project. In a debug state I keep checking to see if the onReceive function is firing, after clicking the button on the widget. I can get it to work, and then not work randomly by removing the intent filters, or changing the labels on the intent filters. It's bizzare, also the androidmanifest is auto generated so what is shown in the manifest, isn't what is actually running in the manifest.

WidgetProvider.cs Class

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Appwidget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


using Terminal;

namespace MultiApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "WidgetProvider")]
    [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Terminal",Exported = true, Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE", "WIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK" })]
    [MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/my_widget")]
    public class WidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider
    {

       public static int Counter = 0;

        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
       
            base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);


            foreach(int appwidgetId in appWidgetIds)
            {
                // Build the remote views for the widget
                var remoteViews = BuildRemoteViews(context, appwidgetId);



                // Update all instances of the widget with the new remote views
                appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(appwidgetId, remoteViews);
            }
         




        }


        public RemoteViews BuildRemoteViews(Context context, int appWidgetIds)
        {
            //Initialize our widget view, basically pointing to our main widget layout xml
            var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_layout);





            //Initializing a new Intent variable, within our current context, and widget provider class
            var clickIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetProvider));

            //Settings that clickIntents action to be 'Widget_Button_Click'
            clickIntent.SetAction("WIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK");

            //Initializing a pending intent variable, basically saying that the button will be clicked at some point
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

            //Associating the pending intent, to our widget_button pointer in our xml file
            widgetView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_button, pendingIntent);



            return widgetView;
        }











        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnReceive(context, intent);

            //If Intent Receive is our widget button click
            if (intent.Action == "WIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Congrats", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Widget Layout Class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/widgetbackGround">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">



            <ListView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/terminalViewDraw"
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_marginRight="13.0dp" />



            </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        


            <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:id="@+id/widget_button"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.terminal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I can get it to work, and then not work randomly by removing the intent filters, or changing the labels on the intent filters. It's bizzare

Comment: To update any of yall having a similiar issue, when I removed the toast message, the onReceive function started working as functioning. Bizzare.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see you used the `Android.Support.V4.App` namespace in your project. And I suggest you migrate the support package to the [AndroidX package with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx).

And then, you can remove the `[Activity(Label = "WidgetProvider")]` of the class `WidgetProvider`, because it's not an activity.

In addition, I created a new project to test your code. I can reproduce the problem:

> For some reason, the button keeps working and then not working; even when I made no modifications to the code or project. In a debug state I keep checking to see if the onReceive function is firing, after clicking the button on the widget. I can get it to work, and then not work randomly by removing the intent filters, or changing the labels on the intent filters

If you restart the project in the debug mode, the existed widget on the device will stop working suddenly. And you need to create a new widget and remove the old one. Then the `OnReceive` will be always triggered when you click the button.

Removing old one and adding new one worked for me. Finally, I tested on the android 13 and found that the Toast will not show even though the `Toast.MakeText(context, "Congrats", ToastLength.Short).Show();` is executed.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the fix. Why is it that, this code worked for my Counter app flawlessly, and it doesn't work for this one. It's the same exact code, the only difference is that the button is nested under my children nodes, rather than the root layout.

Comment: When I remove the old widget and add new one. The toast will show when I clicked the button. I can reproduce the problem in your project.